# django models multiple table inheretence: can I remove the OnetoOnefield link with the parent class for only one field in the childModel

Tags: django, django-models

So in the example code below I'm trying to remove the OneToOnefield link between 'type2' and the Child class to avoid confusion and make things neater. I tired chucking the 'parent_link' kwargs in the desired field however that didn't work.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
    type2 = models.CharField(parent_link=False)##

class Child(Parent):
    different_type = models.CharField()
    different_type2 = models.CharField()
```

Comment: didn't understood what you are asking? please be more descriptive

Comment: Is there a way to remove one of the attributes of the parent class from the child class? I thought initially it would be through breaking the OnetoOneField link, but I think mentioning that convoluted my question